# Sending image via bluetooth is split into packages

Tags: android, image, bluetooth, file-transfer

I modified the sample Bluetooth Chat application with a feature of sending image. I ran into a problem I can't figure out. The sample app needs a string to send and receive data. I am suing Base64 to convert the bitmaps to byte then to string so I could send the text with the selected image. If I send a small image (e.g. a fully black image with 4kb size) it is sent and received and displayed in the listview. But when I send larger images, they are split into many packages. This means, instead of one image, I get numerous texts, and the size of array I use to populate the listview will be anyhing more than 1, depending on the number of packages, so my listview is populated with a lot of text.

As it turns out, it depends on the size of the image. I experimented with many images. In case of a photo, whose length (as a string) is 50096, I get 51 packages on the receiver side. In case of another image, whose lenght is 77896, I get 81 packages. So I decided to try with a really small image. I created a black image in Paint, and it was succesfully sent and received. I measured it's length, which was 280. Then I experimented with a white image with a little yellow, which had a lenght of 980. That was also successfully sent. Then I added some black to the image which resulted in 1554 in length. This time I received a couple of texts instead of the image.

So my conclusion is that the length of string is restricted when sending data via Bluetooth, which may be obvious to someone who is familiar with the technology.

What can I do about this? If I knew the max number of characters that I can send in one package, I could calculate the number of packages on the sender side and I could concatenate all the packages on the receiver size.

I show you two images on the receiver side to demonstrate this behavious. The first one is the correct function, the second one is the wrong function:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the receiver portion, as can be found in this function from the bluetooth chat source code:

```
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Specifically, note the `byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];`. You are limited to only 1K. If you want to do more, you need to increase the size of the buffer, or build a method to detect that files are exceeding this buffer size.

A few things of note, should you design a protocol to handle this.

1. You shouldn't need to send this in base 64, the stream accepts binary just fine.
2. Put a header that includes the file type, packet number, and total number of packets. If you want to be really fancy, include a checksum of some sort, to verify the packet is intact.
3. You should include a mechanism to re-transmit missing packets.
4. You might want to send out an initial header, explaining what is coming.

Comment: I cannot change the buffer size as I don't know how big an image the user will send to its partner. Am I right?

Comment: You could, but only if you knew for certain the file size. In general, I would institute some kind of a packet protocol, sending only one packet at a time. It'll give you the best solution. I'll leave figuring out how to do that to you.

Comment: How about this: I check the lenght of the image to send (e.g. 50000), than I calculate the number of packages which is 5000/1024 ~ 49. On the receiver size I add all the 49 incoming strings to an array, then I concatenate the array items. Then I should have the same string in one string, right?

Comment: That pretty much would work, except I think you should add a few bytes as a header. Each packet should know at the very least what packet number it is, and be tagged that it is a photo packet. They probably should include the total number of packets as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this sounds Chinese too me. I guess what you mean is the on the receiver side there is no guarantee that the packages arrive in the right order. That's why I should add a header to them, right? So I guess this header thing should be handled on the sender side where all I know is a String of 50000 characters. Maybe I should create the appropriate number of packages there with the header then send them one by one, right?

Comment: Basically, a header is some extra data sent to package your main data. Basically, you'll be able to tell from the first, say, 20 bytes or so what the next 1000 bytes contain. Both the receiver and the transmitter have to know and agree on what the data packet looks like.

Comment: What character coding should I calculate with? E.g. If I send "XXX1AAA4BBB" the length of the byteArray (byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes("UTF-16");) returns 24. With UTF-8 it returns 11. I need this to calculate the full length of the string to send (the message+the image+other data) and to calculate the number of packages to send.
I experimented with the packages, they do not arrive in any predeterminable order. The header was a good idea.

Comment: The usual size for something like this is between 1-4K, take your pick.

Comment: What do you mean? You told me I can send 1024 bytes in one package, the question is how many characters can I include in that package? I tried 1024, 511, 512, and some packages come twice, some don't come at all. Maybe the problem lies in this question

Comment: If you do it right, some packages shouldn't come twice. Basically, you have to keep a list of what packages have been received, and the receiver has to tell the sender to send the ones that it hasn't gotten yet.

Comment: This is getting too complicated for me. I accept your solution as this is the way to go.